# Can "adjectives that function like nouns" refer to a single object?

Tags: adjectives, nouns

Many websites I saw say that "adjectives that function like nouns" (the + adjective) refer to a group of objects, not a single object. For example, from [The Britannica Dictionary](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/eb/qa/adjectives-used-as-nouns):

> *She gives money to the poor.*
> *Nurses care for the sick.*
>
> The words poor and sick here are used to refer to poor people and sick people, ... A lot of adjectives are used this way, many referring to classes of people ...

###### My question is:

Is it possible to use those adjectives to refer to a single object?

For example:

> A young man and an old man in the park.
> The young is John and the old is Tom.

Comment: You'll be easily understood, but it'll sound like you're being poetic or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The young" and "the old" are valid examples of adjectives that can be turned into nouns in the right context. You don't have the right context for two reasons:

1. The noun is plural. For example, "the sick" refers to more than one sick person.
2. The nouns do not refer to a specific group, but rather to a group in the abstract. For example, "the young" refers to young people in general. If there is a specific group of young people, you have to refer to them as "the young ones" (which also works in the singular).

So you can say:

> ... The young one is John and the old one is Tom